# What is 'delegate removal' before 'delegate combination' pattern for?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, delegates

In many Unity code examples where one has to subscribe to editor callbacks, you frequently meet the following pattern:

```
Undo.postprocessModifications -= OnPostprocessModifications;
Undo.postprocessModifications += OnPostprocessModifications;

// then, later, in some other method
Undo.postprocessModifications -= OnPostprocessModifications;
```

I used to do the following (inside an `EditorWindow`):

```
void OnEnable()
{
    Undo.postprocessModifications += OnPostprocessModifications;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    Undo.postprocessModifications -= OnPostprocessModifications;
}
```

**Question:**

What exactly is that delegate removal before delegate combination pattern for ?

> Is it solely to ensure extra safety or does it has other benefits?

Comment: Probably misguided attempt to remove all previous additions of "OnProcessModification" (as `-` only remove one https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Events)

Comment: delegate can be `+=` many times , and it will recive many times , so `-=` to make sure it only have one action regist in delegate

Comment: After thinking for quite a while, I have posted an answer I believe would justify this approach!

Answer (score 1):

It is useless, and it certainly not a 'pattern', first of all it works under the assumption that you have only one instance of the delegate subscribed to this event, which if you do `-=` then there's none but what if there are somehow 2 instances subscribed then `-=` still leaves another one subscribed and after it you do `+=` they're back to 2.

If anything this `-=` then `+=` helps with is, it tells you that you're losing track/control over the events or the flow of your program, and this attempt to control it, still fails.

Your approach for `+=` on enable and `-=` on disable if maintained correctly for all listeners, then you should never have to use that 'pattern'.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found why they use such pattern:

Unity has `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` behavior, that is, code continues even after an exception.

Doing so would prevent piling up callbacks and consequently experience weird code behavior.